# Query String Formatting not working in MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to create a url with query string in MCV application 
Here is the code

```
 <%= Html.ActionLink(Resources.Strings.SignIn_lbl, "SignIn", "Account", new { lang = ViewData["user-language"] })%>
```

and here is the generated url

```
mydomain.com/Admin/Account.aspx?Length=7
```

Comment: What do you have defined as the route? Why is it generating a aspx page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're most likely using the wrong overload of `Html.ActionLink`

If I remember correctly, you may be using the overload that also takes in the `htmlAttributes` parameters, so just pass in null.

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(Resources.Strings.SignIn_lbl, "SignIn", "Account", new { lang = ViewData["user-language"] }, null)%>
```